# How to implement polymorphism correctly with protobuf.js and reflection

Tags: c#, typescript, protobuf-net, protobuf.js

Suppose I have a class hierarchy implemented in c# with `Protobuf.net`. (There would also be a `Rectangle` class which implements `Shape`, but I've omitted this for brevity.)

```cs
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Circle))]
public class Shape {
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Circle : Shape {

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Radius {get;set;}
}
```

I want to represent this same class hierarchy in TypeScript using `protobuf.js`. However, I can't seem to figure out how to map back the 'oneof' field to the subclass.

This is the best I've been able to come up with:

```js
// It's not possible to make this inherit from 'Shape'
class Circle extends Message<Circle> {
  @Field.d(1, "int32")
  radius: number;
}

class Shape extends Message<Shape> implements IShape {
  @Field.d(1, Circle)
  circle: Circle;

  @OneOf.d("circle") // ,"rectangle"
  which: string;

  // Implements the property on ICircle
  get radius(): number {
    return this.circle.radius;
  }
}

interface IShape {
}

interface ICircle extends IShape {
  radius: number;
}

function isCircle(shape: IShape): shape is ICircle {
  return (shape as any).which === "circle";
}

const shape = new Shape({
  circle: new Circle({ radius: 5 }),
  which: "circle"
});

const buffer = Shape.encode(shape).finish();
const decoded = Shape.decode(buffer);

if (isCircle(decoded)) {
  const itsACircle: ICircle = decoded;
  // Do something
}
```

This feels hacky to me, because:

1. We have to expose all the possible sub-class fields as properties on the base `Shape` class (in this case the `radius` property of `Circle`).
2. None of the classes actually implement `ICircle`, so if we fail to properly expose some properties, the compiler won't warn us.
3. The type guard relies on a cast to `any`.

**Can anyone suggest a better way of achieving this?**

Comment: can you not just use `var proto = Serializer.GetProto<Shape>();` and feed that .proto schema into protoc to get a js compatible version? (I don't think there's a true ts code-gen yet, though)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @MarcGravell. I tried that and protoc produced a similar class hierarchy to `protobuf.js`, albeit far less readable. Its implementation of `Circle` does not inherit from `Shape`; `Circle` can only be accessed via `getCircle()` on `Shape`.

Comment: Indeed; protobuf *doesn't natively support inheritance*; protobuf-net hacks it in via `oneof`, but: you are restricted by the tools available on each platform